# Want to display correct answer and player selected answer at the end of android quiz game

Tags: android

I am currently have a quiz app which consists of a question & four buttons which is options. At the end of quiz, the app displays the correct answers for all the questions. 
now I want to display correct answer and player selected answer at the end of quiz.
Here's the code that I currently working to display the answers.

```
public static String getAnswers(List<Question> questions) {
int question = 1;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

for (Question q : questions){
    sb.append("Q").append(question).append(") ").append(q.getQuestion()).append("? \n");
    sb.append("Answer: ").append(q.getAnswer()).append("\n\n");
    question ++;
}

return sb.toString();}
```

and my QuesActivity is:

```
private void setQuestions() {
    //set the question text from current question
    String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion()) + "?";
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qText.setText(question);

    //set the available options
    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
}





@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {


    if (!checkAnswer()) return;

    if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
        Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
        Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
        Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else{
        Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}





private boolean checkAnswer() {
    String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
    Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getAnswer()+" "+answer);

        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {   
            Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
            currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();
        }
        return true;
    }


private String getSelectedAnswer() {
    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    if (b1.isPressed())
    {
        return b1.getText().toString();
    }
    if (b2.isPressed())
    {
        return b2.getText().toString();
    }
    if (b3.isPressed())
    {
        return b3.getText().toString();
    }
    if (b4.isPressed())
    {
        return b4.getText().toString();
    }

    return null;
}}
```

Comment: useranswer showing null value.

Answer (score 2):

Add another property in Class Question named, userAnswer. One field will be for correct answer and one will be for user answer. There will be another propety isCorrect. 
You have a class named Question. It would be like that, I am ignoring the syntax.

```
class Question { 
String mQuestion; 
String mOption1; 
String mOption2; 
String mOption3; 
String mOption4; 
String mCorrectAnswer; 
String mUserAnswer; 
String mStatusOfQuestion (Asked/Not Asked Yet) 
}
```

You will set your questions in a way you are doing right now. But set the class objects as well like and put them in an arrayList.

```
ArrayList<Question> mQuestionsList = new ArrayList<Question>
setQuestion() {
Question mQuestion = new Question();
String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion()) + "?";
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    qText.setText(question);
mQuestion.setQuestion(question);
    //set the available options
    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));
mQuestion.setOption1(answers.get(0));
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));
mQuestion.setOption2(answers.get(1));
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
mQuestion.setOption3(answers.get(2));

    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
mQuestion.setOption4(answers.get(3));
mQuestion.setCorrectAnswer(corectAnswer);
}
```

When user taps on an option set the value of object of question like

```
onUserclick(int position 2) {
   mQuestionsList.get(position).setUserAnswer(tappedOption);
   if(tappedOption == mQuestionsList.get(position).getCorrectAnswer())
      isCorrect = true;
   else
      isCorrect = false;
}
```